# Is there an api to determine if the app is free or not? windows phone

Tags: windows, windows-phone-7

My app have two version, one is total free, another have the trial mode.
so i want to check in code,  when the user run the app, which one is free app, which one is in trial mode, and also if the already purchased by the user.

the IsTrial() api can only check the app with trial mode, is there api to determine if the app is free or not?

Answer (score 1):

> My app have two version, one is total free, another have the trial mode.

You shouldn't do this. Having two identical versions on the marketplace is considered spam. Instead you should have one version, with trial-mode being the equal of free, and paid being well.. paid.

But given you have two identical applications with different XAPs, you could just compile a different version...

Comment: Not to mention this is the exact reason they implemented the trial mode API lol